# Best way to create json with 100+ keys

Tags: c#, json, templates, generics, uwp

I have to create a JSON object that contains 100+ keys and some of them start with a number (2nd_). Because of that, I can't have an object to use it as a template, I had it set it up that way until those pre-fixed numeric keys were added to the web service. I used to have a function to fill that object with reflection but now I need to find a new way.

Is there's a way to have a dictionary with all the keys I need to just start filling it with the data I need? Something like a template dictionary or anything else that can be more elegant?

I tried with DataAnnotations but it newtonsoft json doesn't support the "Display Name" attribute.

Btw, it's a UWP app, so it has .Net Core

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some example JSON?

Comment: Can you show us your code ? , if there is some

Comment: It sounds like you need to deserialize into a dictionary. There are plenty of examples of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using JsonProperty[("1st_key")] data annotation. That way I still can have my class with all the objects mapped and have the numeric key that the web service requires